# Why do I get TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'?

Tags: python

I am typing to get a sale amount (by input) to be multiplied by a defined sales tax (0.08) and then have it print the total amount (sales tax times sale amount).

I run into this error. Anyone know what could be wrong or have any suggestions?

```
salesAmount = raw_input (["Insert sale amount here \n"])
['Insert sale amount here \n']20.99
>>> salesTax = 0.08
>>> totalAmount = salesAmount * salesTax

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#57>", line 1, in <module>
    totalAmount = salesAmount * salesTax
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

`raw_input` returns a string (a sequence of characters). In Python, multiplying a string and a float makes no defined meaning (while multiplying a string and an integer has a meaning: `"AB" * 3` is `"ABABAB"`; how much is `"L" * 3.14` ? Please do not reply `"LLL|"`). You need to parse the string to a numerical value.

You might want to try:

```
salesAmount = float(raw_input("Insert sale amount here\n"))
```

Answer (score 82):

Maybe this will help others in the future - I had the same error while trying to multiple a float and a list of floats. The thing is that everyone here talked about multiplying a float with a string (but here all my element were floats all along) so the problem was actually using the * operator on a list.

For example:

```
import math
import numpy as np
alpha = 0.2 
beta=1-alpha
C = (-math.log(1-beta))/alpha

coff = [0.0,0.01,0.0,0.35,0.98,0.001,0.0]
coff *= C
```

The error:

```
    coff *= C 
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

The solution - convert the list to numpy array:

```
coff = np.asarray(coff) * C
```

Comment: if you don't want to import numpy, you can do: `coff = [i * c for i in coff]`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that salesAmount is being set to a string.  If you enter the variable in the python interpreter and hit enter, you'll see the value entered surrounded by quotes.  For example, if you entered 56.95 you'd see:

```
>>> sales_amount = raw_input("[Insert sale amount]: ")
[Insert sale amount]: 56.95
>>> sales_amount
'56.95'
```

You'll want to convert the string into a float before multiplying it by sales tax.  I'll leave that for you to figure out.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can't multiply string and float.instead of you try as below.it works fine

```
totalAmount = salesAmount * float(salesTax)
```