# can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python, floating-point, sequence

Why do I get an error of "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'"? from the following code:

```
def nestEgVariable(salary, save, growthRates):
    SavingsRecord = []
    fund = 0
    depositPerYear = salary * save * 0.01
    for i in growthRates:  
        fund = fund * (1 + 0.01 * growthRates) + depositPerYear
        SavingsRecord += [fund,]
    return SavingsRecord 


print nestEgVariable(10000,10,[3,4,5,0,3])
```

Comment: I would prefer `SavingsRecord.append(fund)` instead of your `SavingsRecord += [fund,]`, it *may* be faster.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485789/why-do-i-get-typeerror-cant-multiply-sequence-by-non-int-of-type-float)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
for i in growthRates:  
    fund = fund * (1 + 0.01 * growthRates) + depositPerYear
```

should be:

```
for i in growthRates:  
    fund = fund * (1 + 0.01 * i) + depositPerYear
```

You are multiplying 0.01 with the growthRates list object.  Multiplying a list by an integer is valid (it's overloaded syntactic sugar that allows you to create an extended a list with copies of its element references).

Example:

```
>>> 2 * [1,2]
[1, 2, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 21):

Python allows for you to multiply sequences to repeat their values.  Here is a visual example:

```
>>> [1] * 5
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

But it does not allow you to do it with floating point numbers:

```
>>> [1] * 5.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Answer (score 3):

You're multipling your "1 + 0.01" times the growthRate list, not the item in the list you're iterating through.  I've renamed `i` to `rate` and using that instead.  See the updated code below:

```
def nestEgVariable(salary, save, growthRates):
    SavingsRecord = []
    fund = 0
    depositPerYear = salary * save * 0.01
    #    V-- rate is a clearer name than i here, since you're iterating through the rates contained in the growthRates list
    for rate in growthRates:  
        #                           V-- Use the `rate` item in the growthRate list you're iterating through rather than multiplying by the `growthRate` list itself.
        fund = fund * (1 + 0.01 * rate) + depositPerYear
        SavingsRecord += [fund,]
    return SavingsRecord 


print nestEgVariable(10000,10,[3,4,5,0,3])
```

Comment: SO is truly amazing... With only 11 views, there's 5 correct answers  within a minute.

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

`fund = fund * (1 + 0.01 * growthRates) + depositPerYear`

growthRates is a sequence (`[3,4,5,0,3]`). You can't multiply that sequence by a float (0.1). It looks like what you wanted to put there was `i`.

Incidentally, `i` is not a great name for that variable. Consider something more descriptive, like `growthRate` or `rate`.

Comment: @All: Thanks for your prompt responses.
@Nathon: i'm glad you made the comment about the variable name. It's important to get syntax discipline from the start when learning programming.

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
fund = fund * (1 + 0.01 * growthRates) + depositPerYear
```

I think you mean this:

```
fund = fund * (1 + 0.01 * i) + depositPerYear
```

When you try to multiply a float by growthRates (which is a list), you get that error.

Answer (score 0):

Because growthRates is a sequence (you're even iterating it!) and you multiply it by (1 + 0.01), which is obviously a float (1.01). I guess you mean `for growthRate in growthRates: ... * growthrate`?