# Python Regex code that captures information between 2 characters ('=' and 'I')

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

(Yes, I know there are relevant regex questions that ask how to capture information between two characters. I tried, they didn't work for me. I also read the regex tutorials as deep as possible.)

I have this code that uses BeautifulSoup to scrap some information from a website in this form: `Exchange rate: 1 USD = 60.50 INR`

This string is stored in a variable called 'data'. I have to capture '60.50' from this string. I have this code for that:

```
data = _funct()
rate = re.search("?<=\=)(.*?)(?=\I" , data)
print rate
```

It doesn't work. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: How about `=\s(\d+\.\d+)`

Comment: Use mean like this: rate = re.search(=\s(\d+\.\d+), data)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple regex like this:

```
(\w+\.\w+)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/jD2lW8/1)**

As you can see the idea behind the regex is:

```
( ... ) Use parentheses to capture the content
\w+\.\w+  any alphanumeric followed by a dot plus more alphanumeric.
```

If you only want to capture digits you could use:

```
\d+\.\d+
```

[image]

If you take a look at the Code Generator for python you can get the code which is:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(\w+\.\w+)')
test_str = u"Exchange rate: 1 USD = 60.50 INR"

re.search(p, test_str)
```

Comment: What program is that you're using to test the regex?

Comment: Thanks. Another slight issue: I now have grabbed 60.50 and stored it in rate = found.group().  Now, I try to multiply this rate with a float value (1000.00) and it tells me: Error: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'.   Any ideas?

Comment: @intellikid it is because you are multiplying text times float. Ensure to convert all to float first

Comment: hey @KarlKnechtel I put the link "working demo" the page is regex101.com

Answer (score 1):

I believe your regex isn't working because you are missing an open parenthesis at the beginning and a close parenthesis at the end. Also, the backslash `\` before `I` is not necessary (but it does work since `\I` isn't a metacharacter code or anything like that). So you could do the following:

```
(?<=\=)(.*?)(?=I)
```

[Please see Regex 101 Demo here.](https://regex101.com/r/jV4zV4/1)

I think, however, as others have mentioned, there are better ways of going about this, namely to look for digits and a decimal point preceded by spaces. The is a difficulty in what was suggested, however, namely that the exchange rate could be missing a leading digit (it could lead with a decimal point), or the decimal point may not be present at all. With that in mind, I would suggest the following:

```
(?<=\=)(?:\s*)(\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)
```

[See Regex Demo here.](https://regex101.com/r/jV4zV4/2)

Comment: Thanks. Another slight issue: I now have grabbed 60.50 and stored it in rate = found.group().  Now, I try to multiply this rate with a float value (1000.00) and it tells me: Error: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'.   Any ideas?

Comment: You want to convert found.group() to a float before trying to multiply - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485789/why-do-i-get-typeerror-cant-multiply-sequence-by-non-int-of-type-float

Comment: Thanks. Done! -> rate=float(found.group())