# This program keeps crashing and i cant work out why?

Tags: python

```
g = raw_input("Any other items enter the price: $")
if (g.isalpha()):
    g = 0.0
if (g.isdigit()):
    g = g
else:
    g = 0.0

Pat=(raw_input('And how many of this item:'))
if (Pat.isalpha()):
    Pat = 0.0
if (Pat.isdigit()):
    Pat = Pat
else:
    Pat = 0.0

g_ = (Pat * g)
Total = (a_ + b_ + c_ + d_ + e_ + f_ + g_)
print'Total: $',Total, '''
```

It keeps returning the error:

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485789/why-do-i-get-typeerror-cant-multiply-sequence-by-non-int-of-type-float)

Answer (score 0):

This line is just assigning a string back

```
if (Pat.isdigit()):
    Pat = Pat
```

I assume you meant

```
if (Pat.isdigit()):
    Pat = int(Pat)
```

Comment: Same for `g`.  `if (g.isdigit()): g = g` will return `g` as `str`.

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Comment: You should convert your variables to `float` and `int` if you are expecting to do arithmetic with them. I recommend you find a good Python text and read about "data types"