# "Simple" Grocery List

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an assignment to create a 'simple' grocery list in python in which the user is asked for names of groceries and their price, then what they are actually buying and the quantity, and then display the total price. The groceries must be put into a dictionary when initially asked, and the second part where the user is asked what they are buying and a price must be in a second loop, rather than just simply asking 'how much are you buying' in the first loop. Here is what I have so far:

```
item = {}
choice = 0

while True:
    x = input('enter item: ')
    if x =='done':
        break
    y = float(input('enter price: '))

    item[x] = (y)

while True:

    x=input('enter item: ')
```

for the second 'while true' statement, I tried this but it didn't work:

```
while True:

    x=input('enter item: ')

    if x =='done':
        break
    z=input("enter amount you want to purchase: ")
    a=z*y
```

It came back with a

```
type error, can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

any help would be appreciated because i get to skip an early morning class on Friday if i submit this beforehand. Thanks!

Comment: `item[x] = y` needs to be inside the loop (indented)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485789/why-do-i-get-typeerror-cant-multiply-sequence-by-non-int-of-type-float)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In second while loop you get error.

```
type error, can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Because you multiplying a string with float variable.
When you write `z=input("enter amount you want to purchase: ")`Python store it as a type 'str'.
You should perform type casting just writing the type you want before input().
In your case Just change This line.
 `z=(input("enter amount you want to purchase: "))`  Into .

```
z=float(input("enter amount you want to purchase: "))
```

Your Program will work.

Comment: man, I just tried it and I can't believe it was that simple. was sitting in class today just staring at the monitor and it was a simple float command? thanks a lot though!!

Comment: @JonathanLudwig please accept an answer by clicking the green checkmark if your problem is solved, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So the first loop should get the list of items and their price.

```
items = {}

while True:
    item = input("Item name: ")
    if item == 'done':
        break
    price = input("Item price: ")
    items[item] = price
```

Then the second part should ask you which item you're buying and for what quantity

```
shopping_list = {}

while True:
    item = input("Item name: ")
    if item == 'done':
        break
    qty = input("How many: ")
    shopping_list[item] = qty
```

So the third section is how you get the total if you have two dictionaries, one *keyed on item name* with values of price, and the other *keyed on item name* with values of quantity. I'll leave that final implementation detail up to you, but will provide some pointers here:

- `some_dictionary[key]` will give the value stored at that key
- if the key doesn't exist in that dictionary, it will raise a `KeyError`
- `some_dictionary.get(key)` will do the same, but if the key doesn't exist it will give `None` rather than raising an error
- `some_dictionary.get(key, any_value)` will do the same, but on non-existent key it will give back `any_value`.
- `sum(any_collection_of_numbers)` will give you the sum of those numbers

Answer (score 0):

Edit: some of the stuff I talk about dropping below was in fact dropped in edits by OP while I was writing.

Variable `choice` is unused so we drop it. The final two lines are not useful as far as I can tell so I drop it. Everything can be connected with a single data member so I wrote it as a class for my own convenience.

```
class Groceries:
  def __init__(self):
    self.items= {}
  def run(self):
    while True:
      x = input('enter item: ')
      if x =='done':
          break
      y = float(input('enter price: '))
      self.items[x] = {"Price": y}
  def get_totals(self):
    for j in self.items.keys():
      self.items[j]["Quantity"] = int(
          input('enter how many {} you want: '.format(j)))
      self.items[j]["Total"
                   ] = self.items[j]["Quantity"] * self.items[j]["Price"]
grocer = Groceries()

grocer.run()
```

With the following inputs:

```
enter item: Spam
enter price: 3.5
enter item: Eggs
enter price: 2.5
enter item: done
```

And `.get_totals()`

```
enter how many Spam you want: 2
enter how many Eggs you want: 4
```

`grocer.items` will be:

```
{'Eggs': {'Price': 2.5, 'Quantity': 4, 'Total': 10.0},
 'Spam': {'Price': 3.5, 'Quantity': 2, 'Total': 7.0}}
```

Comment: Wrapping this in a class seems silly, but it works I suppose.

Comment: I actually like organizing things in classes instead of scripts with naked loops @AdamSmith -- I agree that it's more than is required, but I also think it is more extendable.

Comment: @CharlesLandau it's just not very Pythonic is all. Singleton classes are gross in small scripts like these.

Comment: @AdamSmith I agree with that, but I would expect somebody to build on this with more classes and methods in any real script. This is somebody's homework after all.