# def __rmul__ -> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python

Hi guys I'm new to python and I have an assignment based on Classes and I am getting an error with my code while I try to def__rmul__ . TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'. I would appreciate if someone can explain the error to this code. Thanks a lot ! I also cant upload the entire code for some reason it says : I need to write more ...

```
   def cg(A, b, epsilon=1e-4):
    # k = 0, kk = k + 1
    xk = Vector([0.] * b.rows)
    rk = b - A * xk
    pk = 1. * rk
    for k in range(b.rows):
        alpha = (rk * rk) / (pk * (A * pk))
        xkk = xk + alpha * pk
        rkk = rk - alpha * (A * pk)
        if rkk.norm() < epsilon:
            break
        beta = (rkk * rkk) / (rk * rk)
        pkk = rkk + beta * pk
        rk = rkk
        pk = pkk
        xk = xkk
    return xkk


A = np.array([
    [2., 3.],
    [4., 5.],
])
b = np.array([1., 2.])
x = np.zeros(2)
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        x[i] += A[i][j] * b[j]
print(x)

x = np.dot(A, b)
print(x)

A = np.array([2., 3., 4., 5.])
b = np.array([1., 2.])
x = np.zeros(2)
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        x[i] += A[i * 2 + j] * b[j]
print(x)

A = np.array([2., 4., 3., 5.])
b = np.array([1., 2.])
x = np.zeros(2)
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        x[i] += A[j * 2 + i] * b[j]
print(x)

A = [
    (0, 0, 2.),
    (0, 1, 3.),
    (1, 0, 4.),
    (1, 1, 5.),
]
b = np.array([1., 2.])
x = np.zeros(2)
for i, j, aij in A:
    x[i] += aij * b[j]
print(x)
      class Vector(object):
        def __init__(self, data):
            self.data = data
            self.rows = len(data)

        def __mul__(self, other):
            assert self.rows == other.rows
            return sum([vi * vj for vi, vj in zip(self.data, other.data)])

        def __rmul__(self, a):
            data = [a * d for d in self.data]
            return Vector(data)

        def __add__(self, other):
            assert self.rows == other.rows
            return Vector([i + j for (i, j) in zip(self.data, other.data)])

        def __sub__(self, other):
            assert self.rows == other.rows
            return Vector([i - j for (i, j) in zip(self.data, other.data)])

        def norm(self):
            return math.sqrt(self * self)

        def __str__(self):
            return '{0}'.format(self.data)


    class Matrix(object):
        def __init__(self, rows, cols):
            self.rows = rows
            self.cols = cols

        def cg(self, b, epsilon=1e-4):
            ... # [1]
            self.data = data
            xk = Vector([0.] * b.rows)
            rk = b - A * xk
            pk = 1. * rk

            for k in range(b.rows):
                alpha = (rk * rk) / (pk * (A * pk))
                xkk = xk + alpha * pk
                rkk = rk - alpha * (A * pk)
                if rkk.norm() < epsilon:
                    break
            beta = (rkk * rkk) / (rk * rk)
            pkk = rkk + beta * pk
            rk = rkk
            pk = pkk
            xk = xkk
            return xkk

    #exit()
    class FullMatrix(Matrix):
        def __init__(self, rows, cols, data):
            super().__init__(rows, cols)
            self.data = data

    def __mul__(self, v):
        assert self.cols == v.rows
        data = [0.] * self.rows
        ... # [2]
        for i in range(self.rows):
            for j in range(self.cols):
                data[i] += self.data[i+j*self.rows]*v.data[j]
        return Vector(data)


class SparseMatrix(Matrix):
    def __init__(self, rows, cols, triplets):
        super().__init__(rows, cols)
        self.triplets = triplets

    def __mul__(self, v):
        assert self.cols == v.rows
        data = [0.] * self.rows
        ... # [3]
        for (i,j,d) in self.triplets:
            data[i] += d*v.data[j]
        return Vector(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    sizes = [2 ** i for i in (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)]
    t_full = []
    t_sparse = []

    for N in sizes:
        print('_' * 80)
        print("size   : {0}".format(N))
        # b - vector
        data = [0. for i in range(N)]
        data[-1] = 10
        b = Vector(data)

        # Af - full matrix
        data = [0.] * (N * N)
        for i in range(N - 1):
            data[i + N * i      ] = 10.
            data[i + 1 + N * i  ] = -0.1
            data[i + N * (i + 1)] = -0.1
        data[N - 1 + N * (N - 1)] = 10.
        Af = FullMatrix(N, N, data)
        # solve
        t0 = time.time()
        #~ xf = cg(Af, b)
        xf = Af.cg(b)
        tf = time.time() - t0
        t_full.append(tf)
        print("full   : time: {0:6.2f}s (x[-1] = {1:12.10g})".format(tf, xf.data[-1]))

        # As - sparse
        triplets = []
        for i in range(N - 1):
            triplets.append((i,     i,      10.))
            triplets.append((i + 1, i,     -0.1))
            triplets.append((i,     i + 1, -0.1))
        triplets.append((N - 1, N - 1,      10.))
        As = SparseMatrix(N, N, triplets)
        # solve
        t0 = time.time()
        #~ xs = cg(As, b)
        xs = As.cg(b)
        ts = time.time() - t0
        t_sparse.append(ts)
        print("sparse : time: {0:6.2f}s (x[-1] = {1:12.10g})".format(ts, xs.data[-1]))

        # An - numpy
        An = np.zeros((N, N))
        for i in range(N - 1):
            An[i, i] = 10
            An[i + 1, i] = -0.1
            An[i, i + 1] = -0.1
        # solve
        An[N - 1, N - 1] = 10.
        t0 = time.time()
        xn = np.linalg.solve(An, b.data)
        tn = time.time() - t0
        print("numpy  : time: {0:6.2f}s (x[-1] = {1:12.10g})".format(tn, xn[-1]))
        print()

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(sizes, t_full, 'b-o', label='full')
    ax.plot(sizes, t_sparse, 'r-o', label='sparse')
    ax.set_xlabel('size')
    ax.set_ylabel('times [s]')
    ax.grid()
    ax.legend()

    plt.show()
```

Comment: This particular code won't produce any output because It only defines a class and doesn't run any of its methods. Please post the actual code you're running.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Maybe this is your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485789/why-do-i-get-typeerror-cant-multiply-sequence-by-non-int-of-type-float your data could be of a type that is not the right type for __rmul__

Comment: Can you please provide a *minimal* reproducible example? That is a lot of code of which most is unneeded, seeing how you have problems only with a single operation.

Comment: Get a bunch of not defined error. Put your full code.

Comment: No, do not post your *full* code; post a [mcve].