# Calculation problem in a function in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate something in a function with numbers from an imported list.

```
def calculate_powers(velocities_list):
    power_list = []
    for i in velocities_list:
        power = 8/27 * 1.225 * i * 8659
        power_list.append(power)
    print(power_list)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\Omistaja\PycharmProjects\7_1\wind_turbine.py", line 6, in calculate_powers
    power = 8/27 * 1.225 * i * 8659
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

What to do?

Comment: It seems like `velocities_list` is list of lists, not list of numbers as you think

Comment: Please, provide [mre]. Edit your question to include sample `velocities_list`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485789/why-do-i-get-typeerror-cant-multiply-sequence-by-non-int-of-type-float)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
def calculate_powers(velocities_list):
    power_list = []
    for i in velocities_list:
        power = float(8/27) * 1.225 * float(i) * float(8659)
        power_list.append(power)
    print(power_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

your variable 'i' is probably string, you need to cenvert it to number(float or int,..)

```
power = 8/27 * 1.225 * float(i) * 8659
```

can you provide example of your velocities_list?